# Entity Framework Code First NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First, I've an entity `Articolo` and `ZefiroContext : DbContext` which contains the following declaration:

```
public DbSet<Articolo> Articoli { get; set; }
```

When I run the following code:

```
var a = new ZefiroContext().Articoli;
List<Articolo> r;
if (a != null) 
    r = a.ToList();
else
    r = new List<Articolo>();
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` at line `r = a.ToList();`. I have no `Articolo` entites in my database so I expect my variable `r` to point to an empty `List<Articolo>`.

Comment: Sorry, but why don`t you have an entity `Articolo` in your db? For me this is the error. Just create the table and it will works!

Comment: Can you show the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: What you are expecting seems perfectly reasonable.  I have just checked against my setup and I can run the equivalent code and it does indeed return an empty list.

Comment: I already have a db table for entities Articolo which is empty

Comment: Of course, this "normally" works and doesn't throw a `NullReferenceException`. It looks that something internally in EF during the execution of `ToList()` goes wrong. That's why really more information is necessary, especially the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You just need.

```
List<Articolo> r = new ZefiroContext().Articoli.ToList();
```

Comment: I tryed with  List<Articolo> r = new ZefiroContext().Articoli.ToList(); but I got the same result. I already have a db table for entities Articolo which is empty